# Windows starts services outside startup

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11

I just noticed that on my Windows 11 laptop there is quite some software running which I did not expect. I first noticed QlikSense (a tool I used once several months ago) and now also some more recent ones such as AVG antivirus.

Now that I identified these old pieces of software that are hogging resources I can deal with them simply by uninstalling, but it made me wonder how these managed to get started in the first place?

I just fully shut down my laptop, yet after booting both QlikSense and AVG had services running in the background as shown by Ctrl+Alt+Del. Yet neither was shown in the tab Startup.

Hence my question:

#### Why/how does software that is not in my startup list start running when I start the laptop?

I tried searching a bit, but am mostly finding many results on how to manage your startup list, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: Tasks can be scheduled to open at startup using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Take a look using the [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) app from sysinternals/microsoft.  It can show you EVERYTHING that can be run at startup.

Answer (score 0):

System Services are not Startup programs, but are (mostly) started with
Windows (or by other activation triggers).

These services (mostly) execute inside the Windows kernel, so can be
viewed as part of Windows.

System services are installed by products that want to have a run-always
component that has unlimited permissions.
Antivirus programs are a good example.

When you run these programs through the Start menu, you're calling up
the graphical front-end of the product. In most cases, the real work
is done by the system service running in the background.

You may see all the installed System services by running the
Services applet from the Start menu.